# Starting Docker daemon with sysVinit

Tags: docker, sysv

at the moment I work with **ARM64 based Debian Images and docker**.

I want to **automate the docker daemon on boot** so we do not have to start it manually. But the Images do not use the systemd but **good old sysVinit**.

So I though "quite easy - simple an init script with command "dockerd" (or start-stop-daemon and dockerd as Argument". But no - does not work. The command "dockerd -v" works fine when booting (checked by pipe output to log file). But when execute "dockerd" without an Argument - so simple start daemon - nothing happen - no error no warning nothing is piped to log file.

So my question is - are there any other processes Need to be started or configurations need to be done before this dockerd command can be started?

When boot is finished and i do SSH to device and manually do "dockerd" all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

just for close this question by myself :D

I noticed that in sysVinit system when starting the init-scripts the path variable did not exist (maybe because root starting the processes).  #

So in my script i just added the path variable and set path to folder of dockerd and everything worked well! :D